# WPF & MVVM Light- Pass object into new window

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, mvvm-light

I would like to learn the most proper way to go about this: I have a Listview in my GameView that is bound to an `ObservableCollection<Adventurer>`. Upon double-clicking on a cell, I need a new window (or something else if anything is more appropriate) to open and display data about the correct `Adventurer` according to the cell. So far I haven't been able to. This is what I have so far (it's not much, but nothing I've tried has worked).

The trigger/command in my ListView in `GameView.xaml`

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDoubleClick">
        <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding Mode=OneWay, Path=ShowAdvCommand}"
                            CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=AdvListView, 
                                                       Path=SelectedItem}"
                            PassEventArgsToCommand="True" />
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

And the command in GameViewModel.cs

```
ShowAdvCommand = new RelayCommand<Adventurer>(p =>
{
    System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(p.Name);
});
```

The MessageBox is just there to confirm that Eventtocommand was working.

I essentially need a container that will take in the correct `Adventurer` as a parameter after double-clicking a Listview cell and allow me to display data specific to that instance. I would also prefer to stick to something MVVM-friendly.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

**Update:** I may have made a little progress:

GameViewModel:

```
ShowAdvCommand = new RelayCommand<Adventurer>(p =>
{
    AdventurerView adv = new AdventurerView(p);
    adv.Show();
});
```

AdventurerView:

```
public partial class AdventurerView : Window
{
    Adventurer adv;

    public AdventurerView(Adventurer adv)
    {
        this.adv = adv;
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Now I need to figure out how to make this work in XAML, databinding and such.

**Update:** ...and then I realized that this completely goes against MVVM. Does anybody have any advice?

**Update:** Would MVVM Light's messenger help me here? I've been tinkering with it but haven't gotten it to work.

**Update:** This question is still up in the air. I tried the Prism approach but there was some conflict between Prism and MVVM Light that caused more trouble than it was worth. I'm open to any ideas that are compatible with MVVM Light and the MVVM pattern in general.

**Update:** Also, I would like to do this in a way where multiple popups can exist concurrently, if possible.

Answer (score 5):

In a similar situation, I've used MvvmLight's Messenger, and it worked really well. On double click, send a message from your viewmodel containing the entity you want to pass. Somewhere you will need to register to receive the message, depending on how you have set up your views and viewmodels to be activated.

You could register to receive the message in your MainPage.xaml, and either pass the entity straight to the view's constructor, or access the view's DataContext via an interface to pass the entity, depending on whether you're using a viewmodel in you childwindow. E.g.

```
AdventurerView adv = new AdventurerView();
IEntityViewModel vm = adv.DataContext as IEntityViewModel;
vm.SetCurrentEntity(entity);
adv.Show();
```

The `IEntityViewModel` might look like the following:

```
public interface IEntityViewModel<T> where T : class
{
    void SetCurrentEntity(T entity);
}
```

The viewmodel would implement this interface:

```
public class AdventurerViewModel : IEntityViewModel<Adventurer>
{
    public void SetCurrentEntity(Adventurer entity)
    {
        // Do what you need to with the entity - depending on your needs, 
        // you might keep it intact in case editing is cancelled, and just
        // work on a copy.
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is `IEntityViewModel`? I've been looking around but haven't found any information about it.

Comment: It's not part of any framework, just an interface I use to separate the view from the viewmodel a bit. Editing my question to include an example...

Answer (score 0):

As you've pointed out, proper MVVM wouldn't instantiate the view and pass the view model in through the constructor. You'd be better off binding the ViewModel to the View and there are many different ways of doing it.

One pattern that has emerged is a concept known as a "screen conductor". This is a top level ViewModel or controller that handles which ViewModel represents the main window. Again, many different ways to do this. For example, the ViewModel could raise a standard .net event that the Screen Conductor handles. You could use an message passing system like Caliburn.Micro's EventAggregator or MVVM Light's Messenger. I think MEFedMVVM also has an event aggregator to accomplish this as well.

Caliburn.Micro also has a WindowManager that you can pass in your ViewModel and have it automatically find the corresponding View and manage the window lifetime.

Lots of options. Find the one that works the best for you.

Comment: *[...] proper MVVM wouldn't instantiate the view and pass the view model in through the constructor.* - Hmm, why wouldn't this be proper? The only limitation between `View` and `ViewModel` I know is, that the `View` can know the `ViewModel` but the `ViewModel` must not be aware of the `View`.

Comment: proper mvvm decouples the view from the viewmodel such that there's no direct dependency between them.

Comment: How could something be decoupled from an entity, if it's refering to its properties (binding)? - O.o

Comment: That's the power of WPF -- it's property based binding, not specific Type binding, meaning you can bind any object with those properties and have it work against the view.

Answer (score 0):

This is a nice case for Prism's InteractionRequest. Essentially, you have an InteractionRequest object on your ViewModel that you raise when you double click (inside your double click command). Your view has an Action on it that handles the Raised event and shows the new view. You pass a new ViewModel to that interaction and that's the DataContext for the window that'll display. [Here's some good information](http://blogs.southworks.net/aadami/2012/05/09/prism-interactionrequest-and-popupmodalwindowaction-for-wpf-applications/) to get you started. This is how I display all child windows in my application.

Comment: This looks like the best route for me to take in this scenario. Once I get it working I'll accept your answer. This is all new to me so it might take a bit.

Comment: @DennisE yeah, it took me a bit to get things up and running. The nice thing is that you don't need a full fledged Prism app; you can just use the InteractionRequest objects. Good luck, let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: The code in the link you posted was full of errors and wouldn't compile, but I did find this sample which seems to do everything that I need: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/269364/MVVM-PRISM-Modal-Windows-by-using-Interaction-Requ - That sample includes many classes and I was wondering what I would need of those to achieve what I'm trying to do (which is to display information about an object and possibly send updated data back). If you wouldn't mind helping me get this off of the ground, perhaps we could start a chat?

Comment: I just downloaded the same sample and it built fine for me. What errors are you getting? I can't chat right now. Check the references and make sure it's finding everything. The download comes with all the files you'll need. That link you provided me with is similar but more complicated I think.

Comment: I got the sample you posted to work (I just had to acquire Prism from NuGet) and it certainly looks promising. I'm going to start integrating prism into my project later today.

Comment: Yeah, there are a bunch of MVVM frameworks and Prism is just one. Prism does focus a lot on dependency injection, which can be complicated, but it's not necessary to learn all of that to accomplish what you're trying to do. I do recommend reading as much of the Prism guide as you can though, because it *is* a really nice framework.

Comment: I'm feeling more familiar with how InteractionRequests work now, but unfortunately I'm still having a good bit of trouble integrating it into my project and getting it to do what I need. I think I'll put this question up for bounty when it's eligible.

Comment: Well if you're going to go the InteractionRequest route, you should accept an answer on this question and create a new question. Otherwise, if you put a bounty on this question, you'll most likely get new answers to try. Let me know what trouble you're having integrating it into your project.